# How to insert setTimeOut

Tags: jquery, html, settimeout

```
    <body>
            <script>
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    $('#csgo').each(function(){
                    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

                    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
                        }
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <script>    
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    $('#dota').each(function(){
                    var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

                    var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                            $(this).addClass("slideDown");
                        }
                    });
                });

    </body>
```

So I am having problem where to insert my setTimeOut, whenever I put it on a script,it wont work. So what I was trying to do is to delay the animation for like more than 1 second(s) on page load so I could see the background logo. But what happens is it always animates on page load without any delays of sec.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   //your code goes here....
}, 2000);
```

Enclose your functions in a document ready event like this:

```
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       //your code goes here....
    }, 2000);
});

<script>
$(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $('#csgo').each(function(){
                var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

                var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                        $(this).addClass("slideUp");
                    }
                });
            });

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                $('#dota').each(function(){
                var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

                var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
                    if (imagePos < topOfWindow+400) {
                        $(this).addClass("slideDown");
                    }
                });
            });
    }, 3000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. That is what I did. But the animation wont still delay.

Comment: Did you try putting setTimeout in the body "onload" event?

Comment: @shooper I dont have the onload event.

Comment: @shooper is right just use $(function(){}); for executing your code on document ready.

Comment: @Ragnar I really dont know why the setTimeout wont work I tried to insert it before $(window). Still my problem persists.

Comment: I tried the new code. But on refresh it animates without delays.